# using underscorejs to filter 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this array in javascript: you can see it [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LBa5A/1/)

```
 Array
(
    [2012-10-01] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0

...
            [148] => 0
            [149] => 0
            [150] => 1
        )

[2012-10-02] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1

...
            [148] => 0
            [149] => 1
            [150] => 0
        )

[2012-10-03] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0

...
            [148] => 0
            [149] => 0
            [150] => 1
        )
..............
```

to reduce it, I want to keep only items whose have ones and omit the items with zeros.
like this

```
    Array
(
    [2012-10-01] => Array
        (
            [23] => 1
            [64] => 1
            [70] => 1
            [73] => 1
            [76] => 1
            [108] => 1
            [138] => 1
        )
```

I used underscorejs and this code:

```
 var new_o={};
    var v = _.each(original_array,function(day,key){
        var arr = {};
        _.map(day,function(item,k){
             if (item){
                 arr[k]=item;
             }
        }) ;

        new_o[key]= arr;
    } )    ;
```

it works, but I am pretty sure, I didn't get the best of underscore. 
can anybody suggest a smarter way?

Comment: this doesn't look like a javascript array.

Comment: it is, I just print from the browser console

Comment: what I was trying to say is that you _could_ post the array using javascript syntax to make it easier for potential posters to test your code.

Comment: please look at the fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/LBa5A/1/ (I edited the question above and added a link to the fiddle)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) if you don't use its return value, that's just a slightly more expensive version of [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

As far as simplifying things goes, you're a bit stuck because both Underscore and JavaScript really want to iterate over arrays and you have nested objects (BTW, `{ }` is an *object literal* in JavaScript, `[ ]` is an *array*, they are quite different). Probably the best you can do with your current data structure is to use [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) to iterate over the sub-objects while carrying the new sub-object along; something like this:

```
var new_o = { };
_.each(original, function(day, key) {
    new_o[key] = _(day).reduce(function(memo, item, k) {
        if(item)
            memo[k] = item;
        return memo;
    }, { });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FZRV3/

Comment: thank you. Would you please tell me, how would it be if it was arrays?
I mean if the structures were arrays.

Comment: That would depend on what your array version of the data looked like but it would probably involve [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter).